# Is it possible to write an interactive Apex Console Script?

Tags: apex, developer-console, console, outputtext, inputtext

Is it possible to write an Apex script which will ask the user for input?

Something like:

```
System.out.print("Enter your name: "); 
String name = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: No.  THere is no way to enter user input with apex.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a truly interactive Apex Code interface, partially due to the fact that this could cause indefinite transaction and/or row locks. All locks must be resolved in a single transaction, and transactions cannot exceed a limited period of time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear from your question why you want to do this. If you're looking to shape some type of wizard functionality without diving into visualforce and heavy development, consider there's the [visual workflow feature](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_admin_flow_overview.htm&language=en_US).

This will enable you to create (a sequence of) small screens where users are asked for input. Entirely configuration based.

Comment: No particular why.  Just exploring the boundaries for what is possible and curious whether it would be possible to have interactions without all the overhead of VF development.